# How to determine how many chars in a character array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, char, operating-system

I'm using C with no access to libraries or anything like that since this is kernel code for an operating system. So I can not use sizeOf or any built in function like that. name[] is a character array that holds the name of a file, but the file name can be up to 6 characters long, and I want to determine how long the file name actually is.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
int length = 0;

while(name[length] != 0x0)
{
     length++;
}
```

I also tried it with the 0x0 replaced with '\0' but it still didn't work.

Ideally, it would iterate through the char array and stop once it reaches the end of the file name, but I'm pretty sure that it keeps going past it.

Comment: Read up on strings in C. when creating the string, you need to add `\0` at the end.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Your code should work.

Comment: 1) a string or a char array? 2) Would you guys define *sizeof* a library function?

Comment: You cannot `sizeof`? This is part of the language, how could this possibly be the case???

Comment: In any case, assuming that `name` could be storing more than one `\0` (or possibly `name` is not even a statically allocated array), your method is fine. If you know for a fact that `name` is a statically allocated array which ends with exactly one `\0`, then you can improve your method to a simple `sizeof(name) - 1`.

Comment: `sizeof` isn't a library function; it's an operator. And regardless it wouldn't be of any help anyway since your looking or length of content; not size of object. The simple code you have should work if the `char` sequence starting at `name` is indeed terminated. If it isn't you're basically out of luck. As you have not elaborated on what `didn't work" actually means, vtc.

Comment: Generally, with OS calls, char arrays are passed by start address and length.  This allows arrays with embedded zeros to be passed and accommodates languages that do not use NUL terminated arrays to represent strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the array doesn't contain the zero char ('\0') immediately after the last char of your string.
You can solve this directly by adding the '\0' while you are filling-up an array, or by initializing the whole array by '\0' before filling-up.

Comment: That's a question, not an answer. You can post it as a comment.

Comment: Please don't abuse the answer function. Answer questions you can answer until you have gotten the privilege to comment.

Comment: You are right. The filename is taken from the command line and I thought that it would automatically add \0 onto the end of it but it needed to be done manually.